# IPN Message was not send on Button

Tags: button, paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox, live

Ok, first, I setup the listener and this is working fine with the IPN Simulator. I used the samples from https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/
(and of course, modified)
The log was written correctly and the mails are sent.

Now I created a button on PayPal to checkout. (We will sell only one articel for one price).
I configured the variable notifier_url=http://myscript.php
(the same like in the simulator)
The Payment was proceed correctly. I´ve got a notification from paypal and the money is on my account, but the IPN message was not sent.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide PayPal transaction ID and turn to PP technical support for the further checking in the back end.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of your IPNs in the IPN history page and see if they are queued. It happens a lot in the sandbox environment.